# Inductor with center tap - OrCAD

Tags: inductor, pspice, orcad

I am trying to build a circuit in OrCAD, and I have an inductor with tree terminals. which component should I use for it? L=0.02mH[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do, layout a PCB, or simulate it? If you are trying to layout a PCB, you can place any 3-pin symbol and assign the appropriate footprint. If you want to do a spice simulation, you can use 2 inductors with half the value and tap the center.

Comment: @pgvoorhees Yes, I am trying to simulate the circuit. Ok, I will put 2 inductors next to each other, but what do you mean by (tap the center)?

Answer (score 1):

In circuit analysis, your inductor with a center tap is considered to be *two* inductors with mutual coupling.

The way you describe this to a text-based SPICE is with a line that starts with 'K' and specifies a coupling factor between 0 and 1.

Your drawing implies that your coil is air-wound, with all the windings on top of each other.  I haven't played with coils like that; I'm assuming a fairly healthy mutual inductance (more than 0.7), but not close to 1, and if you asked me to promise a figure I'd tell you I'd need to go do measurements in the lab.

Unless you're getting something that comes with a data sheet, in order to find your coupling constant you'll need to build the thing and test it.  Google for how to do that, and if you don't find anything *ask a separate question*.

Wires close to wires have mutual capacitance, so your inductor will have a lot of capacitance, and it'll be distributed.  While you're testing your inductor to find out its inductance and its mutual inductance, you probably want to find out its self-resonant frequency, or at least verify that its self-resonant frequency is higher than you care about.

PSpice has [a graphical way of doing this](https://www.pspice.com/resources/application-notes/using-inductor-coupling-symbols).  I found it by searching on "PSpice" and "mutual inductance".  Searching on "PSpice" and "coupled inductors" should help, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you ignore the fact that on the left are inductors, and on the right is a transformer (the schematic tool doesn't have a "3 terminal inductor"), this is equivalent.

"Center tapped" here means a 3 terminal inductor, where the in between terminal is the terminal-in-common of two equal inductors places in series.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGnlNq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>